# Как сделать в html таблицу с прокручивающимся скролбаром?

Tags: php, html

Как сделать в html таблицу с прокручивающимся скролбаром? То есть, изначально видно таблицу с, например, 10 полями. А чтобы увидеть другие, надо прокрутить скролбар. Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Я попробовал засунуть в текстареа - но чушь получилась.

Answer (score 11):

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <!-- Тут должна быть ваша таблица -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вариант выше тоже не плох, но сделал бы так:

```
<div class="scroll">
  <p></p> <!--или любой другой тэг-->
</div>
```

---

```
/* scroll start*/

.scroll {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
   }

/* scroll end*/
```

Почему auto? На мой взгляд лучше сделать фиксированный блок, как по высоте, так и по ширине. Ведь вы его будете куда-то вставлять. `overflow: scroll;` даст еще и скролл снизу, ИМХО это неправильно и выглядит на сайте немного wrong. Хотя дело каждого!

Comment: @nosensus `overflow-y`, не, не слышал..

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://www.xiper.net/manuals/html/attributes/scrolling.html) по скроллингу в HTML.